# NoClassDefFoundError in JavaFx with Command line Parameters with Selenium Code?

Tags: java, selenium, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to do a JavaFX Application that can receive command line parameters. I can receive the parameters. But I'm having problems when I instanciate the "A" class (from Main.java) that has Selenium (Testing/WebBrowser Automation Library) members inside.

```
// Main.java
package myPackage;

import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        if (getParameters().getRaw().isEmpty() == false) {
            System.out.println("The application was called by Command Line.");
            Map<String, String> params = getParameters().getNamed();
            System.out.println(params.get("a"));            
            A myA = new A();
        } else {
            System.out.println("The application was called executing the jar file.");
            A myA = new A();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

---

```
// A.java
package myPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class A {

    ChromeDriver driver;

    A() {
        System.out.println("New A Instance.");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            this.driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**But when I try to execute it with:** `java -cp MyProject.jar myPackage.Main --a="value1"`

```
The application was called by Command Line.
value1
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException
        at myPackage.Main.start(Main.java:16)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:331)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:297)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 12 more
Exception running application myPackage.Main
```

As you can see, the app get the parameter and prints it (first and second line in this output above)...

I read that line `NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException` but selenium library (2.37.0) is added, and the libs dependencies too. In Netbeans in the `Libraries > Compile` tab

If I run the application using Netbeans `Project properties > run > parameters` and inserting one parameter all is fine. The problem comes when I do the same by Command Line...

I have tried a LOT of things... and I Can't Understand, why ?

Comment: You probably need to add the library to the classpath when executing the application. What you do in Netbeans only takes effect when launching from Netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KnutArneVedaa Thanks for the comment above. I'm PHP programmer, and know almost nothing of Java. But your Insight clarified me that the CLASSPATH is just like the PATH in PHP, just an environment variable and that helped me to solve my problem.

I'm just explicitly defining the classpath directory to my current directory (the project directory), since '.' is the default value, is Optional, and then I use the **-jar** flag to specify the jar file lol...

`java -cp '.' -jar MyProject.jar myPackage.Main --a="value1"`

It Works! Passing parameters and ChromeDriver Instantiation.

Thank You again ;)